# Чи є різниця між поняттями співмірність і сумірність?

Tags: різниця-між-словами

Дані поняття зустріла у проектах Законів України "Про внесення змін до Конституції України (щодо децентралізації влади)" № 2217а від 01.07.2015 року та №2598 від 13.12.2019 року.

Їх застосовано щодо статті 142 Конституції України:

> Держава забезпечує **співмірність** фінансових ресурсів та обсягу повноважень органів місцевого самоврядування, визначених Конституцією та законами України.

в редакції проекту від 2015 року на місці видліленого слова *«сумірність»*, а в іншому — *«співмірність»*

Тлумачення із "Словника української мови":

- [СУМІ́РНИЙ](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), а, е. Який можна виміряти однаковою з чим-небудь мірою; спільномірний. Два відрізки прямої називаються сумірними, якщо вони мають спільну міру (Геометрія, I, 1956, 93).
- [СПІВМІРНИЙ](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) а, е, рідко. Те саме, що спільномірний. Визначення повинно бути співмірним. Це значить, що визначуване і визначаюче поняття мають бути рівні обсягом (Логіка, 1953, 34).
- [СПІЛЬНОМІРНИЙ](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), а, е. Який можна виміряти однаковою з чим-небудь мірою; сумірний. Спільномірні речовини.

Згідно даного словника ці поняття є синонімами з математичної точки зору. Але мене більше цікавить застосування цих слів у юридичному аспекті. Отже,

**Чи є різниця між поняттями співмірність і сумірність?**

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko, СУМ-11, здається, з Вами незгодний. І що означає «від однакових половин»?

Comment: Щодо співмірний, то гадаю, що в словнику помилка. Подивіться на вживання [співмірності дефініції](https://arm.naiau.kiev.ua/books/logika/lections/lection2_4.html). Там йдеться про відповідність / однаковість.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Cумірний

*Етимологічний словник української мови. Том 5. Коломієць, Мельничук. 2006 рік.*

> Су — іменниковий префікс, що означає зв’язок, з’єднання або неповноту,
> в давніх іменних утвореннях типу ... суголосний, ... сумирний, ...
> сутужний.

*Українська граматика. Тимченко. 1917 року*

> 170.6. Су — спільність, додаток і звідси незначність.

*Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови. Бусел. 2005.*

> **Сумірний** — якого можна виміряти однаковою з чим-небудь мірою,
> спільномірний.

#### Співмірний

*Етимологічний словник української мови. Том 5. Коломієць, Мельничук. 2006 рік.*

> Спів — перша частина складних слів типу ... співзвучний, має значення
> “об’єднаний, сполучений, спільний з ким-небудь, однаковий з
> чим-небудь, разом, сукупно з чим-небудь, буквально “наполовину з”,
> “пополам з”. пів — половина.

*Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови. Бусел. 2005.*

> **Співмірний** — те саме, що спільномірний.

#### Спільномірний

*Етимологічний словник української мови. Том 5. Коломієць, Мельничук. 2006 рік.*

> Спіл — по суті означає те саме, що й спів (вибачте, тут від себе, бо
> там лише приклади, які не дають певної чіткості визначень).

*Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови. Бусел. 2005.*

> **Спільномірний** — якого можна виміряти однаковою з чим-небудь мірою,
> сумірний.

*Етимологічний словник української мови. Том 3. Коломієць, Мельничук. 1989 рік.*

> **Міряти** — визначати розмір.

*Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови. Бусел. 2005.*

> **Мірний** — 1. ... 2. Яким вимірюють що-небудь, який є міркою. 3... 4...
>
> **Міряти** — 1. Визначати величину кого-, чого-небудь якоюсь мірою. 2 ...
>
> **Міра** — 1. Одиниця виміру чого-небудь. 2. Те саме, що мірка. 3...
>
> **Спільно** — разом, гуртом, спільними силами.
>
> **Половина** - 1. Одна з двох рівних частин чого-небудь. Складова частина парного предмета. 2. Середина якої-небудь віддалі, якогось проміжку часу і т. ін. 3...

#### Я теж маю слово

Як бачимо з наданої вище інформації — так, є різниця між поняттями співмірний і сумірний. Ці слова мають спільний корінь від слова міряти, міра. Але вони мають різницю у префіксах су- та спів-, що вказують на відмінність. Де су- вказує на близьку міру, а спів- чи спільно- - на половинну міру, тобто на однаковість мір.

Як це може допомогти з юридичної точки зору не підкажу. Але мені теж цікаво щодо юридичної точки зору на різницю цих слів.

Згідно вашого прикладу використання слів сумірність на співмірність та згідно мого розуміння різниці цих слів виходить, що:

- сумірність - держава забезпечуватиме відносно близьке за мірами  фінансових ресурсів до обсягу повноважень органів;
- співмірність - держава забезпечуватиме однакові (половини) міри щодо фінансових ресурсів до обсягу повноважень органів.

Цікаво тільки як це виміряти. Тобто якщо виміряти точно не можливо, то в даному випадку важко буде відрізнити ці два терміни.

Comment: Не бачу причин для цього висновку *тобто на однаковість мір*. Наприклад, співзвучний, це зовсім не та саме такий, що видає однаковий звук.

Comment: Співзвучний - такий що можна почути та порівняти, схожий на інший звук

Comment: Їм байдуже як воно звучить, а виміряти як завжди - вам суди, нам прокуратура. Значення окремих слів можна закріпити потім змінами до Законів.

Comment: @RomanMikhol це не так, ось [співзвучний](http://sum.in.ua/s/spivzvuchnyj) - тут також сказано - *той, що утворює співзвуччя, гармонює*

Comment: Yola, то було моє власне визначення. Якщо утворює співзвуччя, то набуває ознаку музичного терміну. В музиці не існує співзвуччя, але є КОНСОНАНС.

Comment: Andriy Ivanchenko, залежитеме від того як саме ділити, по-братерськи або по-чесному, на дві абсолютно рiвні частини навіть математично не завжди можна поділити, адже і снують більша і  менша половини.

Comment: @RomanMikhol але є *співзвучність нот*, чи не так? І тут ідеться не про однакові чи схожі. Наприклад, ноти не інтервалі в пів тону (найменшому ненульовому інтервалі) неспівзвучні.

Comment: Якщо дві ноти формують одне ціле, це не означає, що вони половини.

Comment: Я вам навів приклад де *спів-* не вказує на однакоівсть мір, тобто ваш висновок хибний

Comment: Яке складне слово включає корінь *пол*? // 
Однакова вага нот в акорді - це лише ваше тлумачення. Якщо ви граєте мелодію, то головною в акорді може бути тоніка або домінанта, а друга нота допоміжною. // 
Якщо в цьому вашому твердженні * спів- чи спільно- - на половинну міру, тобто на однаковість мір* важливий корінь, то це не видно з тесксту вашої відповіді. Якщо він важливий, то відредагуйте відповідь, щоб це було видно. //

Comment: *Слова спільномірний і співмірний включають в собі корінь пол* - можете навести де сказано, що співмірний включає корінь *пол*? Може у мене щось погано відображається. Просто скопіюйте в коментар цитату.

Comment: Я особисто вдячний за цитати зі словників. Але теорію про «половини» теж не підтримую. Якщо слово (_етимологічно_) включає корінь «пол» («пів»), то це ще не означає, що (_сучасне_) його значення обов'язково пов'язане з половиною.

Comment: Yola, розумію що саме ви маєте на увазі, але давайте дискутувати. Спільною мірою для звучання нот може бути частота коливання повітря, яку можна привести до єдиної міри - кількості отриманої в одиницю часу енергії, дійсно, її розмір може відрізнятися. В такому випадку можна казати про сумірність впливу нот на отримане співзвуччя.

Comment: Людина, тварина і комаха співіснують в єдиному середовищі одночасно незалежно одне від одного, спільною умовою їх існування є наявність повітря на планеті (дихання). Так само співзвуччя може виникати з різних окремих звуків. Спільною умовою існування співзвуччя буде одночасне відтворення (звучання) цих нот, а середовищем що поєднує - людський мозок.

Answer (score -1):

**Сумірний** і **Співмірний**

**Сумірний** — такий, що можна виміряти, однаковою з чимось іншим мірою.

**Співмірність** — кількісне співвідношення частин чого-небудь.
Походить від лат. *proportio* «[пропорція](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0))» (в матем., рівність двох відношень). Пропорції визначають відповідність частин, встановлюють систему співвідношення їх між собою і з цілим.

Наприклад, звуки крокування почесної варти можуть бути співмірними до ударів годинника на башті.

Comment: Дякую за спробу. Це не зовсім те, що вимагалася у запитанні. Адже цікавить саме значення слів, а не переклад на інші мови або з інших мов.

Comment: Добре, подякував. Таки змушений надати розгорнуту відповідь. Щодо "чому перекладаємо саме на московську мову", бо зміни до Конституції є наслідком перемовин у нормандському форматі, де були продиктовані російськомовним Пуйлом і записані нашим російськомовним Президентом.

Comment: Sasha, ви абсолютно вірно розумієте тлумачення цих слів і якщо маєте права на редагування моєї відповіді, додайте будь ласка свою. 
Ми не можемо заперечувати, що українська і російська мови споріднені між собою більше за будь-які інші. Тож, щоб визначити істину, маємо переміститися із політичної площини в лінгвістичну. Російський префікс "со-" зазвичай передається ураїнською як "су-" або "спів-" із обмеженнями у застосуванні (коли вживати префікс спів- https://www.ar25.org/article/koly-vzhyvaty-prefiks-spiv.html).

Comment: Щоб краще зрозуміти тонкощі, перекладемо українською російські слова: "совместимый" и "совместный".

Comment: Можливо варто додати пояснення того, що таке спільна міра, наприклад - *Спільною мірою двох відрізків називається відрізок, який міститься в кожному з даних ціле число разів (без остачі). Не кожні два відрізки мають спільну міру, наприклад сторона і діагональ квадрата її не мають.* [(звідси)](https://sites.google.com/site/interestingmatematika/geometria/vidrizki)

Comment: Також я не певен щодо *співмірності*, можливо ви могли б пошукати приклади вжитку цього слова і з цього зробити висновок. У мене склалось трохи інше уявлення про значення цього слова.

Comment: Співмірність перекладається латино, як proportionalitas (proportion-a-litas - залежно від ударів). В українській слово "співмірний" існує, але вживається переважно "пропорційний".